# Android service inside or outside the main app

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

I have a complex app that works, and it has a messaging section. I want to keep it updated with the latest messages that are located on a remote server (mysql)

I need a service to check for new messages on the server. I already did that, but I need to know if it is Ok to implement the service inside the same MAIN app, or is it better to make the service a separate app.
The service uses AlarmManager to fire every minute.

- If the better way is to make the service independent then how can I make two different apps use the same SQLite database?
- If both things are together (service inside main app) then the SQLite is not an issue since it is located in the same folder.

Please give me a solution and an explication for it.

Thanks

Comment: If your service does specific work for your app, then it should be with your app

Comment: Would the fact that the service is "connected" to my main APP make things harder for Android? I mean, aside the fact that the service updates the database that the main app uses... they do not need to be together...

Comment: No, service runs as a background. It won't affect the activity. You can bind to service using a service connection if you need to communicate with the service from activity

Comment: Thank you. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok. Good. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your service does specific work only for your app, then it should be with in your app.

Since the service runs on the background , it won't affect the activity. You can bind to the service using a service connection and communicate with the service from activity.

Check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html on how to bind the service.